# How to bind a function to click event on an embed

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm trying to bin a function to click event on an embed (flash file). But the problem is the support, so **I'm looking for a cross-browser solution**. The first thought was add the onclick attribute to the embed element but in **Chrome** (v. 59.0.3071.115) the click event is never fired, or the **onclick is not working**...

**Code 1**:

```
<embed onclick='myFunction(myOpts)'
       class="item" 
       src="/file.swf">

function myFunction(myOpts){
    console.log('is working!!!!');
}
```

The above code is not working on Chrome. So, I was thinking in a new way to call this function on a click event: a parent div with the onclick attribute and fire the embed click with javascript (to play the Flash), this is the code:

**Code 2**:

```
<embed onclick='myFunction(myOpts, event)'
       class="item" 
       src="/file.swf">

function myFunction(myOpts, event){
    console.log('is working!!!!');
    event.target.getElementsByTagName('embed')[0].click();
}
```

But the embed's click is never fired... So, my question:

**Is there a way to call a function with the a click event on an embed? If the answer is yes, which is the best way to call a function without affecting his behavior?**

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("embedID").onclick = myFunction();` .onclick is the [global eventhandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) for click events.

Comment: I've the same behaviour with the onclick attribute and the onclick event handler @RaisingAgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking for an answer, this is what I did:

Now I use an **object** tag to show the Flash file **instead of** just the **embed** tag:

```
<object id="objectId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96BB-444553540000"  onmouseup="myFunction(myOpts)"
      name="objectName" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="movie" value="flash.swf"/>
      <param name="quality" value="high"/>
      <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
      <embed src="flash.swf" wmode="transparent" width="100%" height="100%" allowscriptaccess="always"
      allowfullscreen="true" name="embedName" id="embedId" data="flash.swf">
      </embed>
</object>
```

And to call `myFunction()` without losing the behaviour of the Flash file I used `onmouseup` instead of `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the current element, pass `this` inside onClick function.

Then you will be able to call `element.click()` inside `myFunction`.

```
onClick="myFunction('test', this)"

function myFunction(myOpts, element) {

    console.log(element, 'is working!!!!');
    // calling here element.click() will trigger myFunction twice
}
```

Comment: But this is not the problem. With the first code the problem is that the function is never called using Chrome. With the second peace of code the problem is allow the embed correct behaviour (if click then play Flash)